# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve VueJS and Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-7

I have a Laravel project and I want to import library from github to my vue component.

Firstly my package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.7.14",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vuejs-image-gallery": "^0.1.6"
}
```

}

Secondly my webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue({version: 2})
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And finally my vue component

```
<template>
<div>
    <Gallery
        :images="images"
        :imageWidth="720"
        :imageHeight="auto"
        :popUpMaxWidth="720"
        :mdCols="4"
        :smCols="4"
        :xsCols="6"
        :lgCols="2"
    />
</div>
```

```
<script>
    import Gallery from 'vuejs-image-gallery';
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

But when I try to do npm run dev I got the problem

> ERROR in
> ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
> (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
> 1:0-42
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuejs-image-gallery' in
> '/var/www/html/blog/resources/js/components' Did you miss the leading
> dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean
> '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of
> '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?
>
> webpack compiled with 1 error

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `vuejs-image-gallery` is a broken library.  Last updated 2 years ago and no real downloads to speak of on npm.  The github page has had no activity either in terms of reported issues or updates. It looks abandoned.  Try to find a more popular / reliable library, or bring the issue up with the library author on github.